# CURL Error: line folding of header fields is not supported

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to do an API Request via CURL, however I am getting

Error:

> line folding of header fields is not supported

Here is my code:

It's worked fine for years but now it won't accept it, I cannot find much online about it,

Code:

```
function random_str($length, $keyspace = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
{
    $str = '';
    $max = mb_strlen($keyspace, '8bit') - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
        $str .= $keyspace[rand(0, $max)];
    }
    return $str;
}   


    apiRequestCall("https://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/", "Categories.json");
    

    function apiRequestCall($host, $params, $data= NULL) {
        /***Function for all API Calls, to get data from API to script.***/
        
        
     $tmHostHeader = array(
        "authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"624KEYKEYKEY3DA530D\",
        oauth_token=\"6CBTOKENTOKENTOKEND3945\",
        oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\",
        oauth_timestamp=\"" . time() . "\",
        oauth_nonce=\"". md5(time()) . random_str(12) ."\",
        oauth_version=\"1.0\",
        Content-Type: application/json,
        oauth_signature=\"9SIGNATURESIGNATUREC\"",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        
      );
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); 
    
    
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => $host.$params,
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 20,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $tmHostHeader,
          ));
    
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    
           
            return($response);
    }
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can see that the various tokens and keys above have been redacted - using those credentials as they are now I get a `400 Bad Request` (unsurprising really) - do you get similar when using those duff credentials as a matter of interest?

Comment: Hi, yes but I can't give out my credentials ?

Comment: Your header array is all wrong, you did not provide an array of _individual_ headers, but you stuck multiple headers into one single string value.